# Unable to parse the request data into object while making request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, redux

I am trying to make a put request to the API in this format.

[image]

In my redux state, the data is in this format.

```
const [data,setData] = useState({})

// Eg: this is the data that is in the state.

{
    'statement_id1':['category_id1','category_id2'],
    'statement_id2':['category_id8','category_id9']
}
```

> In the state there could be n number of objects but for it's only two.
> I making the request for each object.

To deal with the issue I have tried this.

```
Object.keys(data).map(e=>{
 c = data[e].map(a=>{ return {'category_id':a}})
 
fetch('https://example.com/api/',{method:'POST',body:JSON.stringify(c)})
    
})
```

But when I am inspecting the request from chrome dev tools. The payload is going in this form.

> [{category_id: "category_id1"}, {category_id: "category_id2"}]

So in short the question is how can format the request payload which is in the above-attached picture.

- Thanks

Comment: what would be the `key` and corresponding `value` ?

Comment: Can you update your question and provide what the schema for the request body should be?